# The onclick function for the button "Search books" isn't working cause i don't get any alerts...the function SendInform() is not called

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Here is the java script :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function SendInfo(){
    var req;
    alert("hello");
    var subject=document.libform.txt.value;
    var dept=document.libform.dept.value;   
    var url="Lib.jsp?sub="+subject+"&dept="+dept;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        req=new XMLHttpRequest();
        alert("hello");
    }
    else
    {
        req= new ActiveObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        alert("hello");
    }

    try{
        alert("hello");
        req.onreadystatechange = getInfo();
        req.open("GET",url,true);
        req.send();
    }catch(Exception e){
        alert("hi");
    }
    }
    function getInfo(){
        if(req.readyState==4){
            var result=req.responseText;
            document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML=result;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
```

The code for the button is as follows:

button type="button" value="search books" onclick="SendInform()"

what am i doing wrong here?

I see alerts if the function is reduced to this :

```
function SendInform(){
    alert("hello");
        var req;
        var subject=document.libform.txt.value;
        var dept=document.libform.dept.value;   
        var url="Libservlet.jsp?sub="+subject+"&dept="+dept;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            req=new XMLHttpRequest();
            alert("object created");
        }
        else
        {
            req= new ActiveObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        }}
```

the problem is in the onreadystatechange function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working now :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SendInform(){
        alert("hello");
            var req;
            var subject=document.libform.txt.value;
            var dept=document.libform.dept.value;   
            var url="Libservlet.jsp?sub="+subject+"&dept="+dept;
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                req=new XMLHttpRequest();
                alert("object created");
            }
            else
            {
                req= new ActiveObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                alert("hello");
            }       

            req.open("GET",url,true);
            req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if(req.readyState==4){
                    alert("in function");
                    var result=req.responseText;
                    alert(req.responseText);
                    document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML=result;
                }
            };      
            req.send();     
            }


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
onclick="SendInform()"
```

To:

```
onclick="SendInfo()"
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
function SendInfo(){
```

to

```
SendInfo = function(){
```

and it should work

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you put your sendinfo function in a script on windows load and not add it to your button like you have in your code currently.

Try

```
Window.onload = function(){

button =.   document.getElementById('urbuttonid');
 button.onclick = function(){
 Sendinfo();

 }}
```

Alternatively, console.log() at various points in ur code to see the point at which error occurs as I current do not fully understand ur code because of the several alerts